# Cross-domain POST doesn't work with Angular HttpClient but works with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ajax, cross-domain

I am migrating to Angular 13 and I want to use HttpClient instead of jQuery.ajax.

The following jquery code works:

```
function asyncAjax(url: any){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
            },
            url: url,
            data: null,
            contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
              resolve(data) // Resolve promise and when success
            },
            error: function(err) {
                reject(err) // Reject the promise and go to catch()
            }
          });
  });
}
...
const json: any = await asyncAjax(url);
```

However, when I do with HttpClient:

```
private readonly _httpClient: HttpClient;

constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  this._httpClient = httpClient;
}

...
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
const json = await firstValueFrom(this._httpClient.post<T[]>(url, null, 
    { headers: headers, withCredentials: true}));
```

I get:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [url]. (Reason: CORS request external redirect not allowed).
```

Could anyone say how to make it work with HttpClient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your jQuery code you are sending *no data at all* and claiming you are sending *plain text*.

> ```
> data: null,
> contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
> ```

---

In your Angular code you still aren't sending any data, but this time you are claiming you are sending *JSON*.

> ```
> const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
> ```

---

JSON isn't a data type [supported by HTML forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) which means to send it on a cross-origin request the browser will send a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

The server isn't granting permission using CORS in its response to that preflight request and seems to be issuing a redirect instead.

---

The quick and dirty solution here is to send the *same* `Content-Type` header as you were when the code worked.

The better solution is to consider your API design. Why are you using a POST request but not POSTing any data in the first place? Possibly this should be a GET or DELETE request instead.

---

It is also possible that the cause of the redirect is that the value of `url` has changed (maybe from `http://example.com/foo/` to `http://example.com/foo`) and that needs to be corrected.